# How to arrange or stack div classes

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress plugin for a members directory, it basically puts each element in a div and sorts them in a list across the page.

I would like to stack certain divs on top of each other in a column, this image will explain it better than I can in words:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfDCx.png

Unfortunately I cannot create any other divs, I wouldn't know how to alter the plugin for that.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a `float: left;` styling.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dqha6tap/) visualizing (if I get what you're asking properly.)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help.

I've altered that fiddle a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/dqha6tap/2

Do you know how I would stack the blue and green divs on top of each other to make a single column in the middle?

Comment: Thanks, that does help, but unfortunately this code is generated by a plugin in wordpress, so I can't add any kind of wrap or container

Comment: I may have something with display:flex

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how variable the layout is. If you know enough about it in advance you could do something with inline-block like this: jsfiddle.net/bobdye/m6s40sjq/.
(sorry, but I couldn't figure out how to get the editor to let me insert it as a link).